# Core Data: having issue inserting data with relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have two entities (Categories, Event) and they have two-way many-to-many relationship. A Category can have more than one Event and an Event can have more than one Category. Category to Event relationship is optional in a sense that Category can exist without an Event, but Event to Category relationship is mandatory (Event cannot exist without Category). I'm trying to insert events and adding categories to them but I'm getting NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship error. This is my code :

```
private func storeEventsXMLStream(_ xml: XMLIndexer) {

    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator

    // Remove all data before inserting
    // This line of code is necessary because data needs to be downloaded on daily basis.
    // Otherwise, I will get redundant data.
    removeAllExistingData("Event_Ottawa", managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    autoreleasepool { // Scoping is necessary to fix memory leak
        for xmlcat in xml["events"]["event"]{
            let event = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Event_Ottawa", into: managedObjectContext) as! Event_Ottawa
            event.id = Int32((xmlcat.element?.attribute(by: "id")?.text)!)!
            event.website_url_english = xmlcat["website_url_english"].element?.text
            event.website_url_french = xmlcat["website_url_french"].element?.text
            // setting other attributes of events here. Exactly like I did in above 3 line

            // Just another attribute. Storing it a String in Coredata
            var recur_rules = ""
            for rule in xmlcat["recur_rules"]["recur_rule"] {
               recur_rules += (rule.element?.attribute(by: "weekday")?.text)!
            }
            if !recur_rules.isEmpty {
                event.recur_rules = recur_rules
            }


            do {

                var predicateArray:[NSPredicate] = []

               // Categories are inserted to the Coredata before this method call. So I'm fetching the applicable one here.
               for category in xmlcat["categories"]["category"] {
                    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", (category.element?.attribute(by: "id")?.text)!)
                    predicateArray.append(predicate)
                }

                let requestCategory:NSFetchRequest<Category_Event_Ottawa> = Category_Event_Ottawa.fetchRequest()
                requestCategory.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateArray)
                let managedContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
                managedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator

                let applicableCategories = try managedContext.fetch(requestCategory)

                for category in applicableCategories {
                    event.addToCategory(category)
                }


                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }

    }

    // only save once per batch insert
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    managedObjectContext.reset() <-- I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS, when I use the same object context for fetching as insertion

}
```

And the error I receive :

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)\" UserInfo={Dangling reference to an invalid object.=null, NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship 'category' on managed object (0x6100050963f0)
```

If use the same managed object context for both insertion and fetching, I don't get this error anymore. But I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS from the line that reset context object. I learnt it from another post that CoreData is not thread safe. So maybe that was an issue. But how do I resolve this issue? In case it's relevant, Deletion Rule for Event-Category relationship is Nullify and Category-Event is Cascade.

Comment: Some questions/comments: 1) When you add a new relationship to your Data Model file, the `Optional` property is checked by default - you didn't uncheck this at some point? That would be the most simple reason why you're getting the relationship error. 2) Regardless of the error, what you you trying to do/expect to happen when you call `reset()` on the context?

Comment: 3) I'm still getting familiar with using `NSPersistentContainer` class, but is there any reason you're creating context that way rather than using `PersistentContainer.viewContext` for main context and `newBackgroundContext()` to create a background context like sample code shows?

Comment: 4) re thread safety, for any context working on background/private thread, you should perform actions within the context's `perform` (async) or `performAndWait` (sync) closures so to prevent thread-related errors https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506578-perform

Comment: @MatthewS : 1 ) I made sure that the relationship options are set up to reflect my needs. So yes, Category->Event is optional and Event->Category is not optional. 2) I wanted to make sure that no traces of old data left in memory when I perform coredata related operation again. 3) I'm also new to NSPersistentContainer. My code is based off posts I learnt from SO. I read that this approach would allow me to perform in background instead of UI thread and I have 200k lines to insert. I don't know the difference between this approach and yours. I have to look into that. And thanks for the link!

Comment: It probably doesn't make a difference how you create the context - I just hadn't seen it that way.. so might be a red herring. But I think if you call `reset()` within the scope of `managedObjectContext.perform` closure then I think that will prevent the BAD_ACCESS error. Also FWIW when you're importing 100k+ records like this at once, also make sure you experiment with batch size (e.g. every 1000 objects call save/reset to keep memory usage low)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
requestCategory.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateArray)
```

you're creating a compound predicate with ANDs. You're asking Core Data to fetch you all of the categories that have id = 7 AND id = 8 AND ... etc. That's not going to work. The category can only have a single id. You actually want an 'or' predicate in this case.

However, I think the better way to do this is to load all of your categories into a dictionary keyed by their id before you start looping through your XML, and then just pull them out of the dictionary. That will be much more performant than fetching each time.

Also, you can't fetch categories in a separate context and then create relationships between objects from separate contexts. Core Data will crash if you try it.

Comment: Thank for pointing that out. Because it maybe one of the reasons why I'm getting all sorts of strange symptoms (UI stop responding when tapping on category element etc.). But I have one more question. Is it good approach to use core data generated nsmanaged class to stored the category data for the Dictionary you suggested? Or should I declare new Category class for that matter?

Comment: Your existing Category entity makes sense to me. I'm just suggesting an `NSDictionary<NSNumber *, Category *>` to give you quick lookup of your existing categories instead of hitting the database every time. Does that make sense/answer your question?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. I'll mark you ask correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Please post follow up questions if you have them! :)